# Updating computed value only once in Vue composition API when listening to multiple interdependent references

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

What's the best practice for triggering an expensive recalculation only once for a computed value when it depends on multiple references where one reference depends on the other?

Example:

In the following setup, I want `expensiveData` to be computed only once. `expensiveData` is recomputed when `varA` or `varB` change, but `varB` is in turn derived from `varA`. So when `varA` changes, `varB` is bound to change too.

```js
import { ref, watch } from '@vue/composition-api';

// varA is calculated from fetched data
// and updated when the data changes
const varA = ref([
  /* some data */
]);

// varB is data that is derived from varA, but user
// can independently modify varB without changing varA
const varB = ref(null);

// Derive varB from the varA's value
const updateVarB = (a) => {
  const varBValue = /* process varA */;
  varB.value = varBValue
};

// When varA changes, change varB too.
watch(varA, (newVarA) => {
  updateVarB(newVarA);
});

export { varA, varB, updateVarB }
```

`some-other-file.js`

```js
...
// value of varB is changed upon user-triggered event
const someData = ...
updateVarB(someData);
```

`expensive-calc.js`

```js
import { computed, toRefs } from '@vue/composition-api';
...
/* varA and varB are passed as props */
const { varA, varB } = toRefs(props);

const makeExpensiveData = (...args) => /* some heavy lifting */

const expensiveData = computed(() => {
  /* some calculations with varA and varB */
  return makeExpensiveData(varA.value, varB.value)
});
```

What are the possible ways to approach this situation so that `expensiveData` is recomputed only once?

Considerations:

- `varA` and `varB` are semantically different so it doesn't quite make sense to create a new computed value that would bundle them together.

Current solution was to debounce the call to `makeExpensiveData` with `lodash.debounce`. Since `varB` is derived from `varA`, they trigger the recompute in tandem.

However, I'm relatively new to the Vue's composition API, so I wonder if there's any better way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

If `varB` is guaranteed to always be updated after `varA` is updated, you could replace the `computed` with a `ref` and a `watch`.

```
const expensiveData = ref(null);

watch(
  varB,
  () => expensiveData.value = makeExpensiveData(varA.value, varB.value),
  { immediate: true } // <- if you want to access it immediately
);
```

Anyways, is this still reproducible;